# Vue 2.6 with Rollup: import component by variable name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, rollupjs

I am trying to add dynamic routes to my vue router (using router.addRoute()). It works so far, but I get a problem as soon as I try to set a component for my dynamic route.

This is the code that works:

```
var name = "reports";
var path = "reports/foo";
var item = {
    name: name,
    path: path,
    component: () => import( "../pages/reports/Reports_Foo.vue" )
};
```

When calling the page it correctly loads the content of my Reports_Foo.vue

But when I want to load the vue file dynamically, like this:

```
var filename = "Reports_Foo";
var name = "reports";
var path = "reports/foo";
var item = {
    name: name,
    path: path,
    component: () => import( "../pages/reports/"+filename+".vue" )
};
```

It no longer works and I get the following javascript error:

`TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:123456/js/pages/reports/Reports_Foo.vue`

Why? Do you know a way to fix this ?

Edit: I'm using rollup to convert the files into chunks and then reference them.

Comment: Can you try "import(\`../pages/reports/${filename}.vue\`)" ?

Comment: Is `https://localhost:123456/js/pages/reports/Reports_Foo.vue` accessible via web browser?

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI or Webpack directly?

Comment: no the Reports_Foo.vue is not accessible - when I import it without using a variable it is transformed into a chunk file - with the variable its not

Comment: I tried your version, Michal, and it didnt change anything

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063576/how-to-dynamically-import-a-module-which-name-is-defined-by-a-param-with-rollupj might be the explanation why it doesnt work and how to somehow work around it

Comment: It's a good idea to clearly state the bundler in rollup questions or people might assume Webpack  (edited title / tags)

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly loading the `default` export:

```js
var item = {
  name: name,
  path: path,
  component: async () => (await import("../pages/reports/"+filename+".vue")).default
}
```